# Having trouble setting up remote SSH to my Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: linux, networking, router, ssh, raspberry-pi

I am able to connect to my Raspberry Pi 3 while connected to my home network.

I am able to ping my public IP address AND my domain name, **clemons.tk**.

I have logged into my router and setup port forwarding to my Raspberry Pi on port 22.

However, I am unable to connect using either my public IP or domain name. Is this likely an ISP issue or something on my router I am missing?

Here is the output from my attempts:

```
$ ssh -vvv pi@clemons.tk
OpenSSH_7.6p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: resolving "clemons.tk" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to clemons.tk [76.178.29.176] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 76.178.29.176 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host clemons.tk port 22: Connection timed out
```

Comment: Did you forward TCP?

Comment: Most router don't recognize their own external IP, or port forwarding does not work. As a friend or use your mobile to test.

Comment: Is Clemons.tk pointing to the correct ip?  Type what is my ip into google search, is google reporting 76.178.29.176?  If so, next use an online port scanner (I usually use grc.com) to scan for open ports and see if 22 is actually open.

Comment: Can you connect from the outside of your LAN? Read this: [*Cannot access security cameras when on home network*](https://superuser.com/q/1301454/432690) Is your issue the same? If so, research "hairpin NAT".

Comment: @davidbaumann I forwarded TCP and UDP, both and My router's manual claims to support port forwarding:
https://www.linksys.com/ca/support-article?articleNum=140223

Comment: Yes it supports port forwarding. But this does not work from internal IP on some devices. So try from another network

Comment: Got it working. It was simpler than I realized. I did not realize that my modem doubled as a wireless router. So, I had to setup the port forwarding on both the modem and the router in order for the rule to work.

Thank you for the suggestions.